# Create flat lines from feature class of points Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a feature class of points. I wish to create (or find) a tool to create flat (bearing of 0° from East-West Line) lines centred on each point. See illustration of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

As far as I can see, there are two ways to approach this problem;

1. Attempt to go straight to a tool that draws a line extending outwards from the point with a set bearing.
2. Create two points at the end of where I want each line to be, and connect them.

I am not having success with either method. How can I achieve this in Arcmap?

Comment: I would do this using an arcpy.da.SearchCursor and an arcpy.da.UpdateCursor with @SHAPE tokens to simultaneously read the x,y of the points and subtract/add the same amount from the x values to create polyline geometries that maintain their y value.

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a python tool that could do this for lines in as many directions as you care. The difference between this tool and @PolyGeo's idea is that you get one line with his approach, you would get 2 with my tool. If one line is what you want then you could run a dissolve.

The tool is [Create Lines By Bearing](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=2b0c54fe415641e7af8490c4ba7d4bcf).

I would also suggest you look at ArcScripts first as there are *many* tools created by users all freely available and should be your first port of call.